# Books with problems on extremal principle

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Now, I've seen and read quite a few problem solving books but Arthur Engel's 'Problem Solving Strategies' is the only one I've seen where the extremal principle is treated. (Unlike the pigeonhole principle, parity, recurence(through combinatorics), game strategies and invariants which are pretty commonly treated.) I don't know why. All the problems and solutions are extremely elegant !

Extremal principle tells us to pick up an object whoch maximizes or minimizes some properties to help us with a proof. Here's an example.

Let $S$ be a set of points in a plane such that any point in it is the midpoint of two points in $S$. Prove that $S$ is infinite.

Assume it's a finite set. Choose two points, $A$ and $B$ with maximum distance. $B$ is a midpoint of some $CD$. Now, either $|AC| \gt |AB|$ or $|AD| \gt |AB|$. This contradicts our assumption that there can be two points with maximum distance. So, $S$ is an infinite set. 
Can someone recommend a book which has more problems based on this elegant principle ? I haven't found many.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by the 'extremal principle'? is it just picking something achieving an extreme value?

Comment: @amakelov I have explained and given an example

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly common method. One reference that comes to mind (which is specific to plane geometry) is chapter 20 in Prasolov's book, which has apparently been translated into English here: http://students.imsa.edu/~tliu/Math/planegeo.pdf
Some additional googling turns up e.g. this https://www.math.hmc.edu/~ajb/PCMI/pcmi10_b.pdf Putnam preparation list of problems. Just look up 'extremal principle' or 'extreme principle' and you'll be sure to find something ;)

Comment: Did you also do contest math ?

Comment: yeah, some years ago I did :)

Comment: Tell me, is it helpful for graduate school ? I don't have any exposure to actual contests but I do contest problems for their elegance.

Comment: Everything else being equal it is helpful, but how helpful it is depends on your subject: it can range from being used on a regular basis (like in combinatorics, theoretical computer science, etc) to almost not being useful at all (eg in abstract stuff like homotopy theory). Since all else is never equal, whether or not to pursue contest math problems should depend on whether you can be doing more useful things during that same time instead.

Comment: I'm more into combinatorics, discrete mathematics and computer science. Trying to work through AOCP too now. A year and a half ago, I found Engel and AOCP completely inaccessible ! Now, I sense I've made some progress because of a lot of Math I've read from here and there. I'm able to understand most of the problems in Engel and AOCP is making more sense to me now.